# What is a normal cpu temperature for a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Late 2011)?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, temperature

Problem with temperature on this mac:

```
MacBook Pro (13-inch, Late 2011)MacBook Pro (13-inch, Late 2011)
2.4 GHz Intel Core i5
16 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
Intel HD Graphics 3000 512 MB
```

Now I have temperature about 80-100C in 90% of time (without load temperature about 65-70C). I think maybe problem with thermal paste and heatsink.

Before I install Yosemite 10.10 temperature was aroud 60-70 (except youtube videos or some heavy work like video editing and similar).

I tried to disable coherence, reset smc and nvram but without any changes, temperature high even on simple tasks like browsing or work in simpe apps like text editor.

How can I try to prevent overheating or it's a normal temperature for this types of cpu/macbooks?

Cooler works, system show from 4000 to 6200 rpm (that is noisy).

PS. After some observation found that WindowServer with enabled transparency load up to 60% of cpu (and sometimes more), without transparency about 12-40%. So I guess maybe WindowsServer main problem.

Comment: Check your Activity monitor to see who is driving the CPU nuts.

Comment: @Buscar웃 thats what I do first. No critical cpu usage, for example now 84% idle and t71C (mail, safari, todo). I think maybe it's GPU usage by new Yosemite look heats up system (?). On top is WindowsServer 10-20% but sometimes 30+ and more (but anyway 10-20% is not so much).

Comment: what do you use to read the CPU temp?, I question if that 3d party app is working correctly on 10.10.

Comment: you are reporting a CPU temp of 100 Celsius. That is on the high end. The GPU would not heat up your Mac so that level so the CPU would be that high. Something is wrong here.

Comment: I'm use iStat menu and iStats (command line tool from github), they show similar values.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if iStat works well with Yosemite and delivering correct results.

Your CPU temp is on very high end indicating full load of CPU = continuous load of >100%.

Your SMC reset might not have worked so try it again.

Intel made a simple tool that correctly reports CPU load.

A 2011 model should not have a Thermal paste issue, those usually occur after 5 Years (if), and when the conductive paste dries up. 
But if you consider doing something about it, it is in the difficult category to [do it your self](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Early+2011+Heat+Sink+Replacement/5153).

[Intel Power Gadget.](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-power-gadget-20)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. I tried Power Gadget and results pretty close to iStat menu. "SMC reset might not have worked so try it again" - I did it without removing battery, will try again with and without battery. After some logging I think maybe problem in WindowServer process. Any action like scrolling or dragging window and process load 30-40%+ cpu (with transparency more).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact computer with the same problem. I turned on the activity monitor and found that Google Drive was sucking up a TON of CPU. I really don't know why since I  having done anything with my Google Drive in weeks. I quit Google Drive and immediately my CPU usage dropped significantly. The CPU temp also dropped from 185°f at rest to 128°F at rest. The fans have slowed way down too. Give it a try if you have Google Drive.